# comparing user input to a property file in Java

Tags: java, compare, user-input, properties-file

Just wondering, I assume it probably is and I'm just going about it wrong - if there is a way to compare something a user has in putted against that in a property file and see if it matches? (GitCommands is my prop file)

Also here is my button used to search with

```
  JButton btnSearch = new JButton("Search");
  btnSearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //find selected command

            //obtain text from field
            String key_name = textFieldSearch.getText();
            FindSelectedKey();
```

Here is the method

```
public void FindSelectedKey()
{
    if(textFieldSearch != null)
    {

    textFieldSearch.getText().equals(GitCommands.keys());   

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Key could not be found");
    }
}
```

Comment: what have you tried? what programming language are you using? maybe some snippets of what you've tried might help you in getting a relevant answer

Comment: Hi Bogdan - I'm using Java and I only have the current snippet I'm working on my other versions are long gone and deleted

Comment: well you should add your code snippet here to begin with

Comment: and to answer your second question, usually it's Q&A, you answer one question and get one answer :) and to be honest i'm not sure if the snippet above covers other relevant details about your application, it might help letting us now how you are loading the properties etc. are you using any 3rd party libraries? or is it plain Java?

Comment: Just literally plain java - only thing I have other than my java class is just a properties file. I am only loading my properties for the second half of my app as they are displayed in a Jtree. I was thinking  in regards to my first half (search function) the user would just input a value then I could check the file to see if there was a match to be honest - am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the java.util.Properties API with a properties file and load it in your application and read the properties from there.

Like this :

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread()
                    .getContextClassLoader();
            is = classloader.getResourceAsStream(location);//location:your path of the properties file
            properties.load(is);

            properties.getProperty("Your Key");
```

Comment: Daft question but where abouts would I be putting this just within my main class?Thankyou for your answer - I'd upvote if I could!

Comment: Also I've loaded my prop file once specifically for my Jtree - so will this conflict or would I need to now program it different to how your snippet is?

Comment: add this code when you are starting your main method it will load the proerties file and i think it would not conflict the JTree code

Comment: The Jtree is still working fine thanks I've just checked it - Just trying to get what you /Yale said now :)

Everytime I use : properties.getProperty("Your Key");  my app throws a hissy fit and I always get a null pointer exception,any idea why?

Comment: Just check in the properties file you have the "Your Key" key and a corresponding value to it e.g. Key=1234 and in the java code you have properties.getProperty("Key");

Comment: Yeah in my props file I have it so it looks like Key=Value 
In my code I have properties.getProperty("key") but I have it in my method related to the button -should I have kept it with the rest of the code in my main method?

Comment: it should be properties.getProperty("Key") instead of properties.getProperty("key") it's case sensitive

Comment: I changed that  thanks :) In order to check if it's loading the file I'm going to need to put it in my Jpanel temporarily then if I know that works then I need to update my method for my button to actually search the file and display output :)

Answer (score 0):

Properties are key value pairs built from a file. You can use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html to create the properties object. Then to search it you can use getProperty() method. If will return null if the property key is not found.

Comment: Thanks Neeraj I knew I needed to use the getProperty() method I just didn't know how to do it properly :)